# Android Application Error Message on Unity Deploy

Tags: unity-game-engine

The following error message is displayed when I install the project and try to run it on my android device:

"The application AndroidTest (process com.Test.AndroidTest) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again."

My android version on the device is 2.3.5 And I am building it for the lowest build option in Unity, which is Android 2.3.1 API level 9.

Please can anyone help ?

Here is the log file:

```
03-17 23:32:55.374 I/ActivityManager(  127): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.Test.AndroidTest/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity } from pid 236

03-17 23:32:55.414 I/[POST_RESELECT](  236): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$START@400e4f40,-1,0,-1,0)

03-17 23:32:55.424 I/[POST_RESELECT](  236): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$END@401052c8,-1,0,-1,0)

03-17 23:32:55.444 I/[POST_RESELECT](  236): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$START@400e4f40,-1,0,-1,0)

03-17 23:32:55.444 I/[POST_RESELECT](  236): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$END@401052c8,-1,0,-1,0)

03-17 23:32:55.444 D/PhoneWindow(  236): couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40587178 has no id.

03-17 23:32:55.444 D/Background traffic light(  236): traffic light: GREEN, mBackgroundTrafficLight = false

03-17 23:32:55.474 I/ActivityManager(  127): Start proc com.Test.AndroidTest for activity com.Test.AndroidTest/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity: pid=16583 uid=10075 gids={}

03-17 23:32:55.565 W/dalvikvm(  236): disableGcForExternalAlloc: false

03-17 23:32:55.575 W/dalvikvm(  236): disableGcForExternalAlloc: false

03-17 23:32:55.635 D/AndroidRuntime(16583): Shutting down VM

03-17 23:32:55.635 W/dalvikvm(16583): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400205a0)

03-17 23:32:55.675 E/AndroidRuntime(16583): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

03-17 23:32:55.675 E/AndroidRuntime(16583): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Test.AndroidTest/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find native library: main

03-17 23:32:55.675 E/AndroidRuntime(16583):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1830)

03-17 23:32:55.675 E/AndroidRuntime(16583):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1851)

03-17 23:32:55.675 E/AndroidRuntime(16583):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)

03-17 23:32:55.675 E/AndroidRuntime(16583):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)

03-17 23:32:55.675 E/AndroidRuntime(16583):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

03-17 23:32:55.675 E/AndroidRuntime(16583):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)

03-17 23:32:55.675 E/AndroidRuntime(16583):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)

03-17 23:32:55.675 E/AndroidRuntime(16583):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

03-17 23:32:55.675 E/AndroidRuntime(16583):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)

03-17 23:32:55.675 E/AndroidRuntime(16583):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)

03-17 23:32:55.675 E/AndroidRuntime(16583):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)

03-17 23:32:55.675 E/AndroidRuntime(16583):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

03-17 23:32:55.675 E/AndroidRuntime(16583): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find native library: main

03-17 23:32:55.675 E/AndroidRuntime(16583):     at android.app.NativeActivity.onCreate(NativeActivity.java:187)

03-17 23:32:55.675 E/AndroidRuntime(16583):     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)

03-17 23:32:55.675 E/AndroidRuntime(16583):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)

03-17 23:32:55.675 E/AndroidRuntime(16583):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1794)

03-17 23:32:55.675 E/AndroidRuntime(16583):     ... 11 more

03-17 23:32:55.685 W/ActivityManager(  127):   Force finishing activity com.Test.AndroidTest/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity
```

Comment: you should post logcat

Comment: Thnks for the commet, but what is logcat? I'm realy noob in all related to developing games for android ?

Comment: You can access it via DDMS http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html

Comment: Is this log file helpful ?

Comment: yep. take a look at this string "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find native library". You can show the manifest or you can google "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find native library unity" to find a solution

Comment: Thank you so much !!! I will search it. I tried this game on 2 devices, the first works (with higher android version) and the second breaks. I realy doont know if this problem comes from Unity3d or my device.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. I solved by change the emulator device that support ARMv7. Maybe your device that you use is not ARMv7 or you can check on setting > Android > Device Filter. Hope this can help.